# Invalid model formula in extractvars when trying to display scatter matrix

Tags: r, scatter-plot, scatter, scatter-matrix

When trying to create a scatter matrix in R, I am using the pairs function inputting columns 1, 6, 11, and 14 as so:

> pairs(~ 1 + 6 + 11 + 14, data = housing.df)

but getting an invalid model formula error:

> pairs(~ 1 + 6 + 11 + 14, data = housing.df)
> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
> invalid model formula in ExtractVars

What does it mean, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: You can't specify column indices in a formula like that. You need to use column names. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input  that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: data: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/
imported in R using: housing.df <- read.csv("<path>",header = FALSE)

R version 4.0.3 on Windows

Comment: That was it, it worked when I inputted the column values

Answer (score 0):

`pairs(~ V1 + V6 + V11 + V14, data = housing.df)`